# Div is not centering inside Div

Tags: html

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}

.iconBar div {
  float: left;
  font-size: 18px;
}

div.iconBar {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.iconBar img {
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="iconBar">
    <div>
      <img src="http://eventtoursolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/convenient.png"> Convinient, All-Inclusive Weekly Price
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://eventtoursolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Insurance.png"> Insurance
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://eventtoursolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/mileage.png"> Milage Allowance & Expenses
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://eventtoursolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/tractorTrailer.png"> Tractor & Expandable Trailer
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://eventtoursolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/professionalDriver.png"> Professional Driver
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Why is my div not centering? I am having trouble making the div center. I tried a bunch of solutions from other people and i got it to work in one of the tests, but this one is not working?

Edit: iconBar Div, i want the text and icons to be centered. It needs to look like the bottom picture

[image]

Comment: `Why is my div not centering?` - Which div? the `wrapper`, the `iconbar` or every div in the markup?

Comment: haha.. was gonna ask same question

Comment: info added to the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by your image remove `float:left` and add `display: inline-block;` to `.iconBar div {...}` and add `text-align: center;` to `div.iconBar {...}`

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}

.iconBar div {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
}

div.iconBar {
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.iconBar img {
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="iconBar">
    <div>
      <img src="http://eventtoursolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/convenient.png"> Convinient, All-Inclusive Weekly Price
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://eventtoursolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Insurance.png"> Insurance
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://eventtoursolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/mileage.png"> Milage Allowance & Expenses
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://eventtoursolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/tractorTrailer.png"> Tractor & Expandable Trailer
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://eventtoursolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/professionalDriver.png"> Professional Driver
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Magical! Could you explain a bit on how or why `display: inline-block;` worked? thanks